# Regrex query in DB2-LUW

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I need a regrex query to match any string having given character. So i tried for example

```
SELECT wt.CHGUSER FROM "CDB"."WTBALL" wt where  REGEXP_LIKE (wt.CHGUSER, '^\d*115*$');
```

So i am expecting to fetch all the strings having 115 somewhere in between each string. I tried many combinations but i am getting empty column or weird combination.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure You need a regex? You write "all the strings having 115 somewhere in between each string", but test for a all-digit string with "115" somewhere...
Btw. this could be done also without regex:

```
WHERE LOCATE('115', wt.CHGUSER) > 0
  AND TRANSLATE(wt.CHGUSER, '', '0123456789') --if You really want to test all-digit string
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use the native "LIKE" expression?
`where wt.CHGUSER like '%115%'`
This will give different results than your regexp because your expression is looking for '115' so long as there is a digit immediate before and after it.  A more generic regexp, which matches your question, would be `'.*115.*'`

Answer (score -1):

What about -

```
REGEXP_LIKE (wt.CHGUSER, '^*\d115\d*$');
```

Comment: I resolved it with `REGEXP_LIKE (wt.CHGUSER, '^\d*115\d*$');`